# Scroll View in UITableViewCell won't save position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have some `UIScrollView`s in my `UITableView`.

My problem is that if I scroll the scroll view in the first cell to another position, the fourth cell will also be at that same position.

Same for the second and the fifth, the third and the sixth...

Is there a way for the scroll views in the cells to keep their position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save the actual content offsets of your `UIScrollView`s in an array, retreive the value after a scroll happened in a custom delegate and set the offset to the saved value in `cellForRowAt`.

**CustomCell.swift**

```
weak var delegate: CellScrollViewDelegate?
let scrollView: UIScrollView!
var contentOffset: CGPoint!

func setUpCell() {
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset
}


[...]

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    delegate?.horizontalCellDidScroll(indexPath: indexPath, contentOffset: scrollView.contentOffset)
}
```

**TableViewController.swift**

```
var cellScrollContentOffsets = [[CGPoint]]()

func horizontalCellDidScroll(indexPath: IndexPath, contentOffset: CGPoint) {
    cellScrollContentOffsets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = contentOffset
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath)
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.savedContentOffset = cellScrollContentOffsets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.setUpCell()

    return cell
}
```

**Delegate.swift**

```
protocol CellScrollViewDelegate: class {
    func horizontalCellDidScroll(indexPath: IndexPath, contentOffset: CGPoint)
}
```